# I need to run a function, after the previews function has been finished

Tags: jquery, html

My HTML:

```
<img id="pv" src="#" />
<input type="file" onClick="preview(input)" />
```

My JQuery Code:

```
function preview(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#pv').attr('src', e.target.result)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
  b();
}

function b() {
  crop_dp(); //This will run the jcrop.
}
```

Ok now my problem is, when the preview() function is called the b() function is also called at the same time. But I need to call the b() function only after the preview() function has been completed. I try Googleing it and the other try other stackoverflow ques. But they were no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call in the call back, Instead of calling after the function. It is an async call.:

```
function preview(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#pv').attr('src', e.target.result);
      // Instead of calling after the function. It is an async call.
      b();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }

}

function b() {
  crop_dp(); //This will run the jcrop.
}
```

Comment: Ok! But it won't let me till 6 min.

Comment: Sure @Riyadh. Will wait... Cheers.

Comment: @Riyadh Curious to know why you changed the accepted answer?

Comment: My mistake... it might been an accident.. sorry.

Comment: Hey, can i contact with you

Comment: @Riyadh My email address is in my profile page. But still, it is `praveen@praveen-kumar.uk`. Sure.

Comment: Thnx. But can i get ur fb id

Comment: @Riyadh Sure.. Send me a mail. I will send my FB ID. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `b` in the load callback as reading the file content is an async job

```
function preview(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#pv').attr('src', e.target.result);
            b();//need to do it here
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

function b() {
    crop_dp(); //This will run the jcrop.
}
```